# RobotFramework Create Dictionary with an integer value instead of string

Tags: python, robotframework

```
Create Dictionary   sensor_id=1
```

when using Python gives me:

```
{'sensor_id': '1'}
```

Where really I want:

```
{'sensor_id': 1}
```

Is there anyway to prevent the robot framework from adding these quotes to my integer values?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In robot, you can coerce a string to an integer by putting it inside `${}`

```
${foo}=  create dictionary    sensor_id=${1}
```

With the above, the value in the dictionary will be an integer.

For more information see [Number Variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#number-variables) in the robot framework user guide.

Comment: Brilliant, It works. Doesn't reduce readability too much either.

Comment: Or in the more general case, cast the variable to integer before the assignment, e.g. '${value}   Convert To Number   ${value}', and then '${foo}=  create dictionary    sensor_id=${value}'

Answer (score 2):

- literals evaluate to strings (`sensor_id=1`)
- `${}`'d literals evaluate to integers (`sensor_id=${1}`) - this is what you need to answer your question
- `${VAR}` variables default to strings
- Use `${VAR} =  Convert To Integer  ${VAR}` to rebind a variable's type